# How to unpack htmlAttributes in a span tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have `htmlAttributes` generated - originally for the purpose of creating a link with the attribute using `Html.ActionLink`.

Now, based on some condition, I would like to create a `<span>` tag instead and put the attributes in there. Is there anyway it can be done easily ?

Eg: something like:

```
<span <%= htmlAttributes.Unpack() %> > Some txt </span>
```

OR

```
<%= Html.SpanTag("Some txt", htmlAttributes) %>
```

OR anything similar without wresling too much with the already generated htmlAttribues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could easily build an Html.Span Extension something like :

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DatePicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string text, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary attributes =
            htmlAttributes == null ? new RouteValueDictionary()
                                   : new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name, true);
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(name);
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(text);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

I didn't test this but should be working